# Aggregation in time intervals - R language

Tags: r, intervals, aggregation

I have data like following:

```
    time:                   a:
    2016-02-01 16:00:00      111
```

The value of column "a" could be any number and NA. For each "time" number/NA is assigned to "a".
The data is ordered by "time" ascending.
My task is to aggregate periods when the "a" equals NA (R language).
Examplary data set:

```
     2016-02-01 16:00:00 NA
     2016-02-01 16:00:01 NA
     2016-02-01 16:00:02 NA
     2016-02-01 16:00:03 NA
     2016-02-01 16:00:04 21
```

So there are 4 "NA" values in a row and it takes 4 seconds. So it should be aggregate to interval 0 - 15 sec. The original dataset has about 100000 records and each interval of NA values should be aggregated in the same way.
Intervals are not equal, it starts with 0-15 sec and ends with 1-2 days.

What is appropriate way to do this?

Comment: What do you want the output to look like? `rle` will be useful.

Comment: the output should be like: `Interval` and `count` as headers, and then in column with intervals something like (0, 15s), .... [1d, 2) and in column with counts something like 123. I thought about knith::kable. I have to display result with the use of Markdown template. I'm completly new with R so I would be really thankful for help

Comment: You need to edit with [a minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). Without seeing enough of what you have and what you want, it's impossible to provide a thorough answer. It probably only needs `rle` and maybe `lubridate`'s `interval` object type, but it could be structured in any number of ways.

Comment: One could try the cut command: cut(df$time, breaks= "15 sec").  See help for "cut.POSIXt".  This could bin the data into the desired time intervals.